# Choose specific key then show specific value without ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular and I'm trying to display a value from a key-value pair based on the key. I've seen solutions to this using ng-repeat but that seems messy. Is there a better solution that doesn't involve controller logic?

E.g.

Say I have fruits with ID's and names in an array:

```
$scope.fruits = [
 {id:1, name:"apple"},
 {id:2, name:"banana"},
 {id:3, name:"cherry"}
];

$scope.fruit_selection = 3;
```

Then in my view I'd like to see

```
<a>{{some logic that shows cherry}}</a>
```

Comment: Why can't you access fruits directly using fruit_selection index?

Comment: I'm new-ish to javascript. Could you show an example?

Comment: `<a>fruits[fruit_selection - 1].name</a>` This will display "cherry". Is this what you want?

Comment: I used 1,2,3 for my example but it could be any number for any fruit like 6,4,99 etc.

Comment: Which fruit do you want to display? All or just one?

Comment: just the one that matches the id. There shouldn't be more than one, and if there is, just the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.pickFruitById = function() {
    $scope.fruits.forEach(function(element){
    if(element.id == $scope.fruit_selection) {
        $scope.fruitToBeDisplayed  = element.name;
     } 
});
}
$scope.pickFruitById();
```

In HTML:

```
<a>{{fruitToBeDisplayed}}</a>
```

`pickFruitById` is a function that will pick the fruit with id `fruit_selection` and will assign it to `$scope.fruitToBeDisplayed` You can then access it from HTML by using `{{}}` notation

The reason why I put the logic in a function is that if `$scope.fruit_selection` changes then you can call this function from HTML to get the new `fruitToBeDisplayed`.

Comment: This seems to work well, though I'm going to experiment for a version that works using mostly angular directives if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/zeoznzqv/), with some less code/logic.

Please find the code below:

HTML:

```
 <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
    <span ng-repeat="item in fruits">
      <a ng-if="item.id == fruit_selection">
         {{item. name}}
      </a>
    </span>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
   var app = angular.module("app", []);

   app.controller ('test', function($scope) {
      $scope.fruits = [
         {id:1, name:"apple"},
         {id:2, name:"banana"},
         {id:3, name:"cherry"}
       ];
      $scope.fruit_selection = 3;
    });
```